# "put X down to" vs. "put down X to": subjects of verbs with two particles

Tags: word-order, phrasal-verbs, particles, particle-shift

> I expect I would have to put down many coats to do the job. (*[SOURCE](http://www.nytimes.com/1987/08/02/nyregion/home-clinic-q-a-aligning-a-door-latch-bolt.html?pagewanted=all&src=pm)*)

One factor to distinguish phrasal verbs from prepositional verbs is particle movement. Phrasal verbs can place the particle before or after direct object, whereas the preposition in prepositional verbs must precede the noun. (*Biber et al. 1999*)

So, I'm confused when analyzing the fragment "put down many coats to" because I'm not able to distinguish whether "put ... " is a phrasal verb or a prepositional verb. The confusion arises when I read in the Oxford Dictionary of English, under 'put' → 'phrasal verb', the form "**put something down to**" is correct.

So, the above sentence would be rewritten as follows :

> I expect I would have to put many coats down to do the job.

Am I right? If not, how do I correctly distinguish phrasal verbs from prepositional verbs in the cases, like this one, where there are two particles (in this case 'down' and 'to')?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, the phrasal verb is **put down** as you have correctly said that the particle can go either side of its direct object

> to put down many coats
>   to put many coats down

The *to* immediately following that phrase is part of *to do the job*.

> In order to completely hide the horrible colour, I expect I would have to put down many coats of paint.

---

Now, there is an idiom *to put down to*, as in "I **put** the high cost of food **down to** the price of fuel" which means "I **believe the reason for** the high cost of food **is** the price of fuel". Your original example doesn't use this, and it's not a separable phrasal verb (as in your *Biber* reference) because *down to* can only come after the direct object. You can tell the difference because the idiomatic *put down to* is always followed by a noun or noun phrase.

Comment: @tchrist Sorry; it's been a long day. Let's use the word *particle*. In fact I'll give up and go to bed...

Comment: I also fail to understand this “true” phrasal verb thing you are talking about. Do you mean that “to put something down to something else” is a “true” phrasal verb and “to put something down” is not?  Why?  You can put something down, or up, or off, or inside.  I guess those are just adverbs, and that this isn’t a special idiom.  Is that it? I’m pretty certain that “to put something down to something else” is indeed a phrasal verb.

Comment: This answer makes sense to me. It's not obvious OP is even aware of the idiomatic *put sth **down to** sth*. So far as I can make out, he's preoccupied with drawing a distinction between *phrasal/prepositional verbs* (I'm good with [the BBC saying they're the same thing](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv54.shtml)), and with placement of the word "down" (either side of the object - makes no difference).

Comment: The definition of 'phrasal verb' differs depending on who is defining it. You might want to say *separable* phrasal verb rather than *true* phrasal verb.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, I like that.

Answer (score 3):

There is no misreading possible, simply because *“to put **something** down to **something**”* doesn’t allow the *down* to be separated from the *to*. These are two completely different senses, of which only the last is an idiomatic phrasal verb with a special meaning:

- I put the whole thing down the drain to empty out the pail.
- I put the whole thing down to get a fresh start on it in the morning.
- I put the whole thing down to poor management.

I don’t recognize any of the rest of the question as making any sense.  It’s too much hyper-analysis, the kind of stuff they needlessly saddle ESL learners with, making them think it is a real thing, and really important, when it is not. The proof is that nobody ever teaches this sort of silliness to native speakers at grammar school.

Comment: But most sources mention the type of NP that constitute the object of phrasal verb as important factor for the position of the particle and the same source states that the bondage between verb and particle increases with the level of idiomaticity; however, in this last case the question remains what idiomaticity mean.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Was that a question?  If so, I can’t understand it. Please rephrase, more simply. What are you asking?

Comment: No, tchrist; that was a comment.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Well I still don’t understand its relevance to what I wrote, particularly given that you’ve begun your comment with “But...”.